# Quart python to get multiple content inside formdata using request.files

Tags: python, quart

This is sample code to get multiple entries in formdata my python program received from react TS. But when i run the code it only repeat 1 time though there are more than 1 entries in my formdata. please kindly help. thank you guys.

for name, uploaded_file in (await request.files).items():
#print(file.filename)

i tried to get multiple entries in formdata my python program received from react TS